# What is effect of sperm in blood?

Tags: reproduction, pathology, hematology

Staphylococcus aureus, Streptococcus pyogenes, and Clostridium perfringens all produce hyaluronidase.
Each of these bacteria are pathogens (*use hyaluronidase as a virulence factor to destroy the polysaccharide that holds animal cells together, making it easier for the pathogen to spread through the tissues of the host organism*)

> [The role of hyaluronidases in cancer is controversial, however there is substantial evidence of increased hyaluronidase activity in malignancies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyaluronidase).

We know, human sperm also produces hyaluronidase (for penetration of ovum),
So what would happen if sperm enters blood (Like:via cuts or wounds on genitals)?

Comment: Ciliary Dysentery(Balantidiasis) is caused by Balantidium coli(ciliated protozoan) which causes ulcers in colon and invades mucous membrane by secreting "Hyaluronidase"

Comment: Not much really, blood would be a really hostile environment for sperm. And they would get targeted by the immune system rather quickly. Fertilization of oocyte by sperm is a very specific process, sperm would not be able to "drill" through any type of cells.

Comment: Would there be any effect in body after hyaluronidase is secreted by sperm? You can guess it by examples given by me.@Maljam

Comment: could you link the evidence to your claim *The role of hyaluronidases in cancer is controversial, however there is substantial evidence of increased hyaluronidase activity in malignancies.*?

Comment: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyaluronidase)   is the required link.@gone

Comment: The problem with bacteria in tissues is that they can multiply, causing more damage. A sperm can't multiply. It's effect would be negligible.